# reducing garbage collector overhead for lots of Strings

Tags: java, string, garbage-collection

I'm building a million row spreadsheet and anything done in that process, times a million, can add up to a big hit. One of the problems I'm having is when I process a formula in a cell, I have to parse the formula, adjust the references, then build the formula back up. In the course of this I create 5 - 12 strings (depends on how many objects when tokenizing) that I use and then am done with.

I'm finding that the garbage collector is taking 70% of the time during this processing and the main objects created and then going out of scope to be collected are these strings.

Are there any approaches to reduce the GC hit? (If this was C++ I would just create a pool of strings to reuse.)

The details:

The is for a reporting program. We read the template, merge in the data to generate the final report, perform processing on that final report, and then write it out to disk. The report is held as a document object which in this case is 99% a single table, with 1 million rows (when all the data is merged), each row having 6 cells, each cell having optionally: a formula, a value, and/or a body of formatted text.

In the course of processing this there are a ton of strings created for short uses. The case where it's killing me is where the cell formula is adjusted. The template has a formula in a couple of the cells, something like "=A5+A6" which is then adjusted for the location of each row. I parse out the objects {"A5", "+", "A6"}, adjust each for the row they are now on, then in a StringBuilder put all those back together in a StringBuilder and the toString() that to assign back to the formula String object in the cell.

The difficulty in writing most of the document object to disk is that the document object is not read from, operated on, and a new one written out. To reduce the memory hit and to handle cases where we need to walk across columns as opposed to rows, we work on the object as is adjusting it in place.

The issue is when we get low on memory - the whole thing runs super fast until we get to that point. I'm using YourKit to profile and what's killing it is collecting String objects. Passing StringBuilder objects can help a bit but not a lot as I'm then going to be collecting a lot of those (fewer, but still a lot).

Comment: How about trying StringBuilder/StringBuffer instead of String?

Comment: I'd bet you're barking up the wrong tree. Allocating 6M Strings per seconds is peanuts for the GC. Memory lack is a problem. See my answer. *The amount of work to be performed by the GC is **not** proportional to the number of throw away objects.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This hit has IMHO nothing to do with processing millions of strings. I've just measured that I can create 6 million strings per second sustained rate and the GC is pretty idle.

The problem seems to be that you're running out of memory. This makes the GC work more frequently and harder to keep the program running.

*So do not waste time trying to reduce the allocation rate.*

Get more memory or reduce the consumption. Getting more memory is usually the cheapest way. For reducing memory consumption consider:

- Processing the data so that you don't need to store everything in memory at the same time
- Packing same data. A `char` takes 2 bytes, which means wasting half the memory (assuming you use mostly ASCII).
- Interning some strings. Maybe there are many short string repeated many times...
- Using off-heap memory.

Without your program, it's hard to say more.

Use `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` and `-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps`. This is what I get - [nearly no GC overhead](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/so/GCStringDemo.java):

```
10.075: [GC [PSYoungGen: 442272K->896K(425472K)] 442852K->1476K(769024K), 0.0016600 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
10.323: [GC [PSYoungGen: 425344K->928K(409600K)] 425924K->1508K(753152K), 0.0017150 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
10.558: [GC [PSYoungGen: 409504K->928K(394240K)] 410084K->1508K(737792K), 0.0014760 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
10.791: [GC [PSYoungGen: 394144K->928K(379904K)] 394724K->1508K(723456K), 0.0017070 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
```

Comment: Yes, it is when it gets low on memory that this starts to hurt bad. But it's hurting where I just need all these strings temporarily and if there was some way to reduce the GC hit from all these short usages, then this problem is resolved.

Comment: Also, yeas I looked at writing part out to disk but that is not easy based on how the data in memory is accessed.

Comment: Give us more details. How do your data structures look like? Do you know how the GC can be tuned? Do you use mostly ASCII?

Comment: More details added. It may be that we need to write most of our document out to disk as we process but that is not going to be pretty, or easy.

Comment: @DavidThielen Assuming in runs on company's computers only, I'd try to get more memory. This is the cheapest solution. Maybe you could reduce the allocation rate by not extracting the strings and parsing them inplace instead. This goes against what I wrote above and I'm only mentioning it as it's pretty simple. Maybe I'd pack the strings, a `CharSequence` working over `byte[]` should be simple and could save half the memory. I'd mean a lot of conversions and even more allocations, but with enough memory it should be fine.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not our computers. We're a commercial library that lots of companies use. And some are going toward absolutely gigantic reports so we need to do everything we can. I think creating our own StringBuilder using CharSequence may be as you said our best bet. Sometimes I miss C++...

Comment: @DavidThielen Then I'd suggest to look how to compress strings on the fly. Unfortunately, compressed strings have been drop from Java, but you can sort of run your own. Maybe you can use an `Object` reference, which points to either `String`, or `byte[]`, or maybe `Double` (for computed fields), or whatever. Converting on the fly will cost time, but hopefully not that much. Maybe you post the results then. Or post a new question now?

Comment: @maaartinus Is it possible to completely have no GC? I have been writing a UDP multicast packet receiver for a few weeks, but my boss has been complaining that for such a simple program it should have no GC, and I have tried removing the use of iterators (enhanced for loop etc), reusing objects as much as i can, primitive collections, no wrapper objects for primitive (un/boxing) but I still cant get gc numbers that look like that (or reduce the rate of GC)

Answer (score 2):

Too many objects in memory, means too much of cleanup work for Garbage collector. I believe you can reduce the number of objects created if you use `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer` instead of `String`. Anytime you manipulate a `String` object, a new object is created because of immutable nature of String.

But if you use `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer` to manipulate strings then no new object is created. `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer` are dynamically re-sized but you can also limit it if you chose the initial size of your `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer` appropriately.

In short, lesser objects, lesser work required by Garbage Collector.

Comment: Why a down vote? I am ready to correct myself but please advise.

Comment: Well.  Basically, it is wrong.  *"Too many unused objects in memory, means too much of cleanup work for Garbage collector."*  Unused (unreachable) objects are *cheap* for the GC.  It is the reachable objects that are expensive to deal with.

Comment: It was me... I completely disagree with optimizing this way. And especially I dislike your last sentence. It's not like the GC had to take a dead object and bury it. Quickly dying objects are pretty cheap, they can't cause such an overhead.

Comment: If the OP's program is spending 70% of its time in the GC, the most likely cause is that the heap is not big enough.  (Or a storage leak which is filling the heap with useless *reachable* objects.  Same difference ...) Second most likely is a bad choice of GC tuning parameters.

Comment: I agree with the misguiding usage of "unused", which is removed now. But I still believe that more in-memory objects will keep the GC busy if the heap size is not big enough  for those objects. As there is no code provided, so we cannot determine the scope/lifetime of those objects. My answer is based on few assumption but I don't think it is wrong.

Comment: @StephenC - any suggestion for GC tuning parameters when I have very little free memory left and am making tons of small objects (lots of them Strings) for very short periods of time?

Comment: Just curious, but say I have to append many strings and variables to a StringBuilder, wont that still create many objects as it is resizing the internal char array of the StringBuilder? @JunedAhsan